# AWS Amplify how to sign into Admin UI after running "amplify pull" command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am following this tutorial, and when I do

```
amplify pull --appId <my app id> --envName staging
```

It opens the Amplify Admin UI but I don't know what to log in with?

Has anyone else had this problem?
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-two

Comment: If it opens the Amplify Console, then use  your AWS credentials that you used in [Module 1](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-one/). If the link is taking you to Amplify Admin UI for the app, follow the _[get started from an existing Amplify app](https://docs.amplify.aws/console/adminui/start#to-get-started-from-an-existing-amplify-app)_ guide to enable the UI (if not already) and manage access. From there, you can add/remove access for other users.

Answer (score 1):

Run `amplify init` and then select `Y` to confirm the Project Information. To verify that you have set up the app locally, run `amplify console` and select authenticate with AWS profile

Answer (score 1):

you need to launch studio after creating the backend environment. it will log you into the studio. now run `amplify pull` again and it will ask you if you want to log in to the Amplify Studio using the CLI. Click yes and you're done.

[image]
[image]